# Cannot parse array with HTML code using jQuery's $.parseJSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing, escaping

I am trying to use jQuery's $.parseJSON() to convert a variable into JSON but one of the values in the JSON string consists of HTML code. When I remove the HTML variable and replace with 'test', the variable can be parsed using $.parseJSON and successfully sent to php script using ajax where the objects can be manipulated.

I am trying to figure out how to pass the HTML code into the variable and parse it in order to make this object accessible to my php script. Currently, the questionshtml[index] variable is breaking the script.

I've tried using 'questionsvalues[index].replace("}{", "},{");' in order to remove double quotes and backslashes but the script still breaks. Can someone provide a solution to getting the html code prepared properly to be parsed using $.parseJSON() ?

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var questionstype = [];
var questionshtml = [];
var questionsquestion = [];
//Store all questions, types, and html for each fieldset into 3 separate arrays
for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
  {
 questionsquestion.push($("#formelement_"+i + " legend").text());
 questionstype.push($("#formelement_"+i).attr("class"));
 questionshtml.push($("#formelement_"+i)[0].outerHTML);
  };
  //format values for each fieldset into values format in mysql
  var questionsvalues = [];
  var index = 0;
  for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
  { 
  questionsvalues.push('{"question":"'+questionsquestion[index]+'","type":"'+questionstype[index]+'","html":"'+questionshtml[index]+'"}');    
  index++;
  };

 //format mysql values into JSON format
 var questionsvaluesjson = '{"questions":['+questionsvalues+']}';
 questionsvaluesjson = $.parseJSON(questionsvaluesjson);

//convert to json
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(questionsvaluesjson);

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/project/templates/yoo_nano2/php/saveform.php',
  data: {'formpreviewhtml': formpreviewhtml, 'jsonArray': jsonArray},
  beforeSend:function(){
    // this is where we append a loading image
   $("#formpreview").append('<div style="z-index:3000;" id="divoverlaycontainer"><div id="loaderoverlay"><div class="center" id="loader"><img src="/project/templates/yoo_nano2/images/loader.gif"></div></div></div>');
   }, success:function(data){
alert(data + "Saved form successfully.");
//$('#viewresults').empty();
$('#divoverlaycontainer').remove();
// successful request; do something with the data
//$('#viewresults').html(data);
}, error:function(){
// failed request; give feedback to user
alert("Save was unsuccessful. Please try again.");
$('#divoverlaycontainer').remove();
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: Are you escaping the html content that you have been passing in the json ? If not then do it and try again.

Comment: Also please validate your json response and make sure sure it valid .. try http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json

Comment: I'm not sure how to escape the HTML -- I'm looping through elements on the page and just pulling in the code using jquery : questionshtml.push($("#formelement_"+i)[0].outerHTML); -- can you suggest a method to escape at this step?

Comment: Use http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp to escape the html and similarly we have the unescape() method to unescape the html back to its original form

Comment: Raghu, I think I love you. Thanks!!! Worked perfectly!!! :) Cheers

Comment: you love me? lol...Thanks anyways